New relic shows slow - compoment Custom/Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response::sendContent
New relic shows slow compoment- Custom/Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response::sendContent


Can you add more context to this? only that call does not get any information on why that specific call might be slow
